# In C, is it valid to declare a variable multiple times?

Tags: c

I have the below C code and I am expecting it to throw an error like "multiple declaration of variable", but it is not doing so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;        
int i;    

int main()
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is `0`, but why?

And one more thing below code gives error what is expected

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i;        
    int i;    

    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

O/p is error saying re declaration of i

Comment: i am using online compiler to run this code.

Comment: After the edit: in the 2nd snippet, the definitions of `i` occur inside a function (they don't occur at file scope) and are not tentative definitions.

Comment: Why is not tentative definition when occurs inside block because its just declaration not defination??

Comment: @Amit: a declaration of an object at block scope can be achieved with the `external` keyword: `external int i;`, but it is better to specify such declarations at file scope anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first definition of `i` is a tentative definition (the 2nd is also a tentative definition). They are "de facto" definitions though (and definitions serve also as declarations), no mistake about it.

Quote from [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 6.9.2/2
>
> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks @pmg for your response but can you please put this whole thing in simple way.i mean i can have as many declarations as i want??

Comment: No initializers. No override that says its elsewhere. No conflict. Standard says "in that case, declare here and initialize to zero".

Comment: @Amit: basically, definitions without an initializer (`int i;`) are tentative definitions. C allows multiple tentative definitions of an identifier. Definitions with an initializer (`int i = 0;`) are not tentative definitions and cannot be used more than once.

Comment: Non-tentative definitions are called *external definitions* - you can have many tentative definitions of the same identifier, but only one external definition.