# Trying to demonstrate a case where extern for variables is necessary in C

Tags: c, extern

I am trying to understand extern. According to one of the top answers to
[How to correctly use the extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c)

it's in order to solve the problem of multiple inclusions of a header file resulting in multiple copies of the same variable and thus leading to, presumably, a linking error.

So I tried it by creating the following files:

count.h

```
int count;
```

count.c

```
int count = 0;
```

add.h

```
int sum(int x, int y);
```

add.c

```
#include "count.h"
int sum(int x, int y){
count = count + 1;
return x+y;}
```

sub.h

```
int sub(int x, int y);
```

sub.c

```
#include "count.h"
int sub(int x, int y){
count = count + 1;
return x - y;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "count.h"
#include "add.h"
#include "sub.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", count);
  printf("%d\n", sub(100,1));
  printf("%d\n", count);
  printf("%d\n", add(100,1));
  printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

This compiles and runs fine with output:

```
0
99
1
101
2
```

I get the same output with or without extern in the original count.h file. So what am I missing in the answer?

Now, I thought the answer is that "I'm just declaring multiple copies of count" since there are no header guards, and that is OK because multiple declarations are OK, whereas multiple definitions are not. 
But then if that's the case, I would expect the following to compile, but it does not since I am "redefining count."

```
int main(){
   int count;
   int count; 
   int count = 0;
}
```

According to this answer, int count does count as a definition.
[In C, is it valid to declare a variable multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774759/in-c-is-it-valid-to-declare-a-variable-multiple-times)

Comment: Try adding `#include "count.h"` to "count.c".

Comment: or `gcc main.c count.c` (presuming the GCC compiler via command-line)

Comment: @chux I tried as you suggested and did not see anything different. I'm not sure I would expect there to be any difference because what's one more (there are already multiple *int counts* after pre-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
int count;
```

in `count.h` is actually a *definition*, not a mere declaration. It is a *tentative* definition, but as every tentative definition it gives birth to a normal full-blown definition of `int count` at the end of each translation unit that contains the above.

So, by including your `count.h` into multiple translation units you produced multiple definitions of external object `int count` in your program, which is formally illegal in standard C. It "compiles and runs fine" only because of a compiler extension implemented by many modern C compilers.

According to [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (see section **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**), this used to be OK in the relaxed legacy declaration/definition model employed by Unix compilers back in the day (so called "Relaxed Ref/Def" model). However, more formal K&R C rejected Unix model and replaced it with so called "Strict Ref/Def" model, which already allowed only one definition. Later, the standardization committee settled on a mix of "Strict Ref/Def" model and "Initialization" model, which still allows only one definition. Yet, popularity of "Relaxed Ref/Def" in old Unix compilers is the reason many modern compilers continue to support this model as an extension.

In order to make your program compliant with the requirements of standard C you have to remove the definition of `int count` from the header file and replace it with a non-defining declaration

```
extern int count;
```

This is what makes `extern` useful with variable declarations.

Comment: Is there a way to get the compiler to complain about what I have as is? I have tried gcc with -Wall and -pedantic. I would just like to see a program fail to compile or warn or anything that is fixed by adding extern. But thank you, this clears up a lot.

Comment: @MathStudent - The usual way to avoid this is to *not* have global variables accessed from several different .c files. Declare a function `AddCount` in count.h and hide the variable away in the .c file.

Comment: @MathStudent: I don't know if there's a way to force GCC to complain about it. But I know, for example, that Tiny C compiler will catch this as an error.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in the second case is that you declared `count` multiple times at the same scope *within a function*.  Had you done this:

```
int count;
int count; 
int count = 0;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

You would be fine.  The reason this works is because the declarations without an initializer are a **tentative definition**.

From section 6.9.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> *2* A declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  that  has  file  scope  without  an  initializer, and without a storage-class
>   specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static` , constitutes a
>   *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more
>   tentative definitions for an identifier, and  the  translation  unit 
>   contains  no  external  definition  for  that  identifier, then the 
>   behavior  is  exactly  as  if  the  translation  unit  contains  a 
>   file  scope  declaration  of  that identifier, with the composite type
>   as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.
>
> ...
>
> *4* EXAMPLE 1
>
> ```
> int i1 = 1;         //    definition, external linkage
> static int i2 = 2;  //    definition, internal linkage
> extern int i3 = 3;  //    definition, external linkage
> int i4;             //    tentative definition, external linkage
> static int i5;      //    tentative definition, internal linkage
> int i1;             //    valid tentative definition, refers to pre vious
> int i2;             //    6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
> int i3;             //    valid tentative definition, refers to pre vious
> int i4;             //    valid tentative definition, refers to pre vious
> int i5;             //    6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
> extern int i1;      //    refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i2;      //    refers to pre vious, whose linkage is internal
> extern int i3;      //    refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i4;      //    refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i5;      //    refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
> ```

Comment: Why doesn't it count as a tentative definition within a function?

Comment: @MathStudent At file scope, it could be a declaration or a definition.  In a function, it can only be a definition.